# How to show $[u]_{\alpha;\Omega} \le (\frac{1}{\lambda} +1)[u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

$\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain of $\mathbb R^n$.  Letting
$$
[u]_{\alpha;\Omega} = \sup\limits_{x,y\in \Omega  \\~~ x\ne y}    \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}
$$
and
$$
[u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)}= \sup\limits_{~~~~~~~~~x,y\in \Omega \\ 0<|x-y|< \lambda \text{diam}\Omega}  \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}
$$
where $\alpha,\lambda \in (0,1)$. Then,  how to show $[u]_{\alpha;\Omega} \le (\frac{1}{\lambda} +1)[u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)}$ ?

PS： I really can't deal it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give some information about $\alpha$ and $\lambda$? Does $u$ have some property?

Comment: @user408858  $\alpha,\lambda \in (0,1)$. But $u$ have not special property, it just be the function on $\Omega$.

Comment: Can you tell us where does this question come from? If the domain is convex, then the idea would be to divide the segment joining $x$ and $y$ into small segments of length $\lambda\, diam\Omega$ and use the triangle inequality. But if the domain is not convex but  only connected and so pathwise connected , then the polygonal path joining $x$ and$y$ has length which depends on $\Omega$. So your inequality might be true but with a constant depending on $\Omega$. In a star-shaped domain, to join two points close to each other put in different “rays”, you have to go through the center of the star.

Comment: @Gio67  This question is from a Chinese book about PDE. In the proof of equivalency of $[u]_{\alpha;\Omega} $ and  $[u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)}$. The author state that it is easy to get the inequation, but without proof. Since I fail to prove it, so I ask here. The $\Omega$ just be bounded smooth domain. But if you can show a proof for the convex domain, I appreciate it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\Omega$ is convex, consider $x$ and $y$ in $\Omega$. Assume that $|x-y|>\lambda\operatorname*{diam}\Omega$, since otherwise there
is nothing to prove. Take
$$
n=\lfloor|x-y|/(\lambda\operatorname*{diam}\Omega)\rfloor+1.
$$
Then
$$
n-1<|x-y|/(\lambda\operatorname*{diam}\Omega)\leq n.
$$
Subdivide the segment joining $x$ and $y$ into $n$ intervals of length $\delta=|x-y|/n$. Note that
$$
\delta=|x-y|/n\leq\lambda\operatorname*{diam}\Omega.
$$
Since the function $t^{1/\alpha}$ is convex,
$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\bigg)^{1/\alpha}\le n^{1/\alpha-1} \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^{1/\alpha}.$$
By the triangle inequality
$$|u(x)-u(y)|\le \sum_{i=1}^n |u(x_i)-u(x_{i-1})|,$$
where $x_0=x$, $x_n=y$ and the other $x_i$ are the endpoints of the segment. Since $\delta\le \lambda\text{diam}\Omega$, then
$$|u(x)-u(y)|\le \sum_{i=1}^n |u(x_i)-u(x_{i-1})|\le [u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-x_{i-1}|^\alpha.$$
Now let's raise both sides to the power $1/\alpha$ and let's use the first inequality with $c_i= |x_i-x_{i-1}|^\alpha$. We get
$$|u(x)-u(y)|^{1/\alpha}\le \big([u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)}\big)^{1/\alpha}n^{1/\alpha-1} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-x_{i-1}|
\\=\big([u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)}\big)^{1/\alpha}n^{1/\alpha-1} |x-y|.$$
Raising to power $\alpha$ we get
$$|u(x)-u(y)|\le [u]_{\alpha;\Omega}^{(\lambda)} n^{1-\alpha} |x-y|^\alpha.$$
To conclude, use the fact that
$$
n\leq|x-y|/(\lambda\operatorname*{diam}\Omega)+1\leq\operatorname*{diam}%
\Omega/(\lambda\operatorname*{diam}\Omega)+1\leq1+1/\lambda.
$$